# How to diagnose Java JNI EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION errors in Windows Vista

Tags: java, c++, windows-vista, java-native-interface, swig

We have a Java application that uses some C++ libraries through JNI. The application used to work just fine in Windows XP, but it does not work in Windows Vista, it just crashes the JVM right away.

We also wrote the C++ libraries and produced JNI bindings using SWIG.

We are a little bit clueless on where to start looking for a way to fix the problem.

Here is the EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION that we get:

```
#
# An unexpected error has been detected by Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x771b4335, pid=1320, tid=2004
#
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (1.6.0_01-b06 mixed mode, sharing)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [ntdll.dll+0x54335]
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x041a1400):  JavaThread "AWT-EventQueue-0" [_thread_in_native, id=2004]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x079c8972

Registers:
EAX=0x00100000, EBX=0x07a008d0, ECX=0x00000001, EDX=0x000007ff
ESP=0x04fbf37c, EBP=0x04fbf3a4, ESI=0x079c8970, EDI=0x003b0000
EIP=0x771b4335, EFLAGS=0x00010212

Top of Stack: (sp=0x04fbf37c)
0x04fbf37c:   003b0000 07a008d0 00000000 00000000
0x04fbf38c:   0000000a 04fbf370 00000000 04fbf48c
0x04fbf39c:   7717f1a5 156859ae 04fbf49c 771b4623
0x04fbf3ac:   003b0000 07a008d0 04fbf46c 00000000
0x04fbf3bc:   6688806a 00000000 003b0000 07a008d8
0x04fbf3cc:   6d9bce31 07a00a68 04fbf400 00000003
0x04fbf3dc:   00000080 00000000 045e50d8 01170048
0x04fbf3ec:   01170160 003b0000 003b2e40 00000003 

Instructions: (pc=0x771b4335)
0x771b4325:   f0 3b f3 74 17 8b 47 4c 8b c8 c1 e9 14 22 4f 52
0x771b4335:   32 4e 02 f6 c1 01 0f 84 af 43 00 00 83 7f 4c 00 


Stack: [0x04f70000,0x04fc0000),  sp=0x04fbf37c,  free space=316k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [ntdll.dll+0x54335]
C  [ntdll.dll+0x54623]
C  [ntdll.dll+0x5494b]
C  [kernel32.dll+0x4f10c]
C  [msvcr71.dll+0x218a]
V  [jvm.dll+0xc67de]
j  org.tecgraf.jtdk.core.swig.coreJNI.TdkLoggerManager_initialize__SWIG_1(Ljava/lang/String;)V+0
j  org.tecgraf.jtdk.core.swig.TdkLoggerManager.initialize(Ljava/lang/String;)V+1
j  org.tecgraf.jtdk.core.TdkDefaultInitializer.initLogger(Ljava/lang/String;)V+39
j  org.tecgraf.jtdk.core.TdkDefaultInitializer.initializeTdkLogCacheParams(Ljava/lang/String;II)V+5
j  org.tecgraf.jtdk.core.TdkDefaultInitializer.initializeTdkLogParams(Ljava/lang/String;)V+7
j  infopae.dadosgraficos.services.impl.MapServiceTdkInitializer.defaultInitialize(Z)V+43
j  infopae.main.Main.inicializarVisualizacao(Linfopae/workbench/ui/Workbench;Linfopae/workspace/Workspace;)V+96
j  infopae.main.Main.access$4(Linfopae/workbench/ui/Workbench;Linfopae/workspace/Workspace;)V+2
j  infopae.main.Main$2.run()V+54
j  java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch()V+47
j  java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V+26
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(I)Z+156
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(ILjava/awt/Conditional;Ljava/awt/EventFilter;)V+30
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(ILjava/awt/Conditional;Ljava/awt/Component;)V+11
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(ILjava/awt/Conditional;)V+4
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Ljava/awt/Conditional;)V+3
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run()V+9
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  org.tecgraf.jtdk.core.swig.coreJNI.TdkLoggerManager_initialize__SWIG_1(Ljava/lang/String;)V+0
j  org.tecgraf.jtdk.core.swig.TdkLoggerManager.initialize(Ljava/lang/String;)V+1
j  org.tecgraf.jtdk.core.TdkDefaultInitializer.initLogger(Ljava/lang/String;)V+39
j  org.tecgraf.jtdk.core.TdkDefaultInitializer.initializeTdkLogCacheParams(Ljava/lang/String;II)V+5
j  org.tecgraf.jtdk.core.TdkDefaultInitializer.initializeTdkLogParams(Ljava/lang/String;)V+7
j  infopae.dadosgraficos.services.impl.MapServiceTdkInitializer.defaultInitialize(Z)V+43
j  infopae.main.Main.inicializarVisualizacao(Linfopae/workbench/ui/Workbench;Linfopae/workspace/Workspace;)V+96
j  infopae.main.Main.access$4(Linfopae/workbench/ui/Workbench;Linfopae/workspace/Workspace;)V+2
j  infopae.main.Main$2.run()V+54
j  java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch()V+47
j  java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V+26
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(I)Z+156
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(ILjava/awt/Conditional;Ljava/awt/EventFilter;)V+30
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(ILjava/awt/Conditional;Ljava/awt/Component;)V+11
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(ILjava/awt/Conditional;)V+4
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Ljava/awt/Conditional;)V+3
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run()V+9
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x0442f400 JavaThread "Thread-3" [_thread_blocked, id=2624]
  0x0442ec00 JavaThread "TimerQueue" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4964]
  0x0442e800 JavaThread "Image Fetcher 0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4728]
  0x0442e400 JavaThread "Thread-2" [_thread_blocked, id=3536]
  0x0442dc00 JavaThread "GC Daemon" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4672]
  0x04077000 JavaThread "RMI Reaper" [_thread_blocked, id=112]
  0x04076800 JavaThread "RMI TCP Accept-0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=3348]
  0x04076400 JavaThread "Store infopae.persistencia.ValorDominio Expiry Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3912]
  0x04076000 JavaThread "Store infopae.persistencia.ValorDominio Spool Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4696]
  0x04075800 JavaThread "Store infopae.persistencia.Validade Expiry Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4864]
  0x04075400 JavaThread "Store infopae.persistencia.Validade Spool Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1328]
  0x04074c00 JavaThread "Store infopae.persistencia.Pasta Expiry Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1360]
  0x04074800 JavaThread "Store infopae.persistencia.Pasta Spool Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4948]
  0x04074000 JavaThread "Store infopae.persistencia.Repositorio Expiry Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2984]
  0x04073c00 JavaThread "Store infopae.persistencia.Repositorio Spool Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=376]
  0x04073400 JavaThread "Store infopae.persistencia.Objeto Expiry Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4284]
  0x04073000 JavaThread "Store infopae.persistencia.Objeto Spool Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1816]
  0x04072c00 JavaThread "Store infopae.persistencia.HistoricoObjeto Expiry Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3356]
  0x04072400 JavaThread "Store infopae.persistencia.HistoricoObjeto Spool Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5184]
  0x04072000 JavaThread "Store infopae.persistencia.Atributo Expiry Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3872]
  0x04071800 JavaThread "Store infopae.persistencia.Atributo Spool Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4628]
  0x04071400 JavaThread "Store infopae.persistencia.Classe Expiry Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2588]
  0x04070c00 JavaThread "Store infopae.persistencia.Classe Spool Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3512]
  0x04070800 JavaThread "Store infopae.persistencia.Relacionamento Expiry Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2096]
  0x04070000 JavaThread "Store infopae.persistencia.Relacionamento Spool Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2644]
  0x0406fc00 JavaThread "Store infopae.persistencia.CenarioFoto Expiry Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6108]
  0x0406f800 JavaThread "Store infopae.persistencia.CenarioFoto Spool Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4132]
  0x04103c00 JavaThread "Store infopae.persistencia.DocumentoBeanProvider Expiry Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1976]
  0x04103800 JavaThread "Store infopae.persistencia.DocumentoBeanProvider Spool Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1676]
  0x040d0800 JavaThread "Store infopae.persistencia.DocumentoBean Expiry Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4716]
  0x03f98000 JavaThread "Store infopae.persistencia.DocumentoBean Spool Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4380]
  0x003bd000 JavaThread "DestroyJavaVM" [_thread_blocked, id=3244]
=>0x041a1400 JavaThread "AWT-EventQueue-0" [_thread_in_native, id=2004]
  0x041a1000 JavaThread "AWT-Shutdown" [_thread_blocked, id=4140]
  0x0439a400 JavaThread "AWT-Windows" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=2580]
  0x043a5000 JavaThread "Java2D Disposer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=720]
  0x011c0000 JavaThread "Low Memory Detector" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1716]
  0x011b8400 JavaThread "CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6056]
  0x011b7400 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4836]
  0x011b7000 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3808]
  0x011b2000 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1452]
  0x011a5c00 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3340]

Other Threads:
  0x0119cc00 VMThread [id=3012]
  0x011c8800 WatcherThread [id=1400]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
 def new generation   total 18240K, used 3304K [0x07c00000, 0x08fc0000, 0x0a360000)
  eden space 16256K,  11% used [0x07c00000, 0x07de2cd8, 0x08be0000)
  from space 1984K,  69% used [0x08dd0000, 0x08f27510, 0x08fc0000)
  to   space 1984K,   0% used [0x08be0000, 0x08be0000, 0x08dd0000)
 tenured generation   total 241984K, used 10937K [0x0a360000, 0x18fb0000, 0x27c00000)
   the space 241984K,   4% used [0x0a360000, 0x0ae0e5e0, 0x0ae0e600, 0x18fb0000)
 compacting perm gen  total 13824K, used 13726K [0x27c00000, 0x28980000, 0x2bc00000)
   the space 13824K,  99% used [0x27c00000, 0x28967888, 0x28967a00, 0x28980000)
    ro space 8192K,  66% used [0x2bc00000, 0x2c14c5d0, 0x2c14c600, 0x2c400000)
    rw space 12288K,  52% used [0x2c400000, 0x2ca48c98, 0x2ca48e00, 0x2d000000)

Dynamic libraries:
0x00400000 - 0x00423000     C:\jdk1.6.0_01\bin\javaw.exe
0x77160000 - 0x7729c000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x768c0000 - 0x76994000     C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
0x75330000 - 0x75378000     C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x76760000 - 0x76800000     C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x76bc0000 - 0x76c6c000     C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
0x755b0000 - 0x755c9000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
0x76800000 - 0x768a2000     C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
0x772c0000 - 0x77389000     C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll
0x76d50000 - 0x76d9e000     C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll
0x769a0000 - 0x769aa000     C:\Windows\system32\LPK.dll
0x757b0000 - 0x7584d000     C:\Windows\system32\USP10.dll
0x74f50000 - 0x74f9b000     C:\Windows\system32\apphelp.dll
0x69a20000 - 0x69aad000     C:\Windows\AppPatch\AcLayers.DLL
0x74f30000 - 0x74f4a000     C:\Windows\system32\SspiCli.dll
0x75850000 - 0x76496000     C:\Windows\system32\SHELL32.dll
0x764a0000 - 0x764f7000     C:\Windows\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
0x76600000 - 0x7675b000     C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll
0x76cc0000 - 0x76d4f000     C:\Windows\system32\OLEAUT32.dll
0x751c0000 - 0x751d7000     C:\Windows\system32\USERENV.dll
0x751b0000 - 0x751bb000     C:\Windows\system32\profapi.dll
0x6ded0000 - 0x6df21000     C:\Windows\system32\WINSPOOL.DRV
0x752a0000 - 0x752b2000     C:\Windows\system32\MPR.dll
0x772a0000 - 0x772bf000     C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x76e00000 - 0x76ecc000     C:\Windows\system32\MSCTF.dll
0x7c340000 - 0x7c396000     C:\jdk1.6.0_01\jre\bin\msvcr71.dll
0x6d870000 - 0x6dab7000     C:\jdk1.6.0_01\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll
0x70b30000 - 0x70b62000     C:\Windows\system32\WINMM.dll
0x6d3c0000 - 0x6d3c8000     C:\jdk1.6.0_01\jre\bin\hpi.dll
0x757a0000 - 0x757a5000     C:\Windows\system32\PSAPI.DLL
0x6d820000 - 0x6d82c000     C:\jdk1.6.0_01\jre\bin\verify.dll
0x6d460000 - 0x6d47f000     C:\jdk1.6.0_01\jre\bin\java.dll
0x6d860000 - 0x6d86f000     C:\jdk1.6.0_01\jre\bin\zip.dll
0x6d0b0000 - 0x6d273000     C:\jdk1.6.0_01\jre\bin\awt.dll
0x713c0000 - 0x71400000     C:\Windows\system32\uxtheme.dll
0x710e0000 - 0x710f3000     C:\Windows\system32\dwmapi.dll
0x75060000 - 0x7506c000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTBASE.dll
0x6d500000 - 0x6d524000     C:\jdk1.6.0_01\jre\bin\jpeg.dll
0x6d360000 - 0x6d3b3000     C:\jdk1.6.0_01\jre\bin\fontmanager.dll
0x6d620000 - 0x6d633000     C:\jdk1.6.0_01\jre\bin\net.dll
0x76ed0000 - 0x76f05000     C:\Windows\system32\WS2_32.dll
0x76bb0000 - 0x76bb6000     C:\Windows\system32\NSI.dll
0x74ab0000 - 0x74aec000     C:\Windows\system32\mswsock.dll
0x74aa0000 - 0x74aa6000     C:\Windows\System32\wship6.dll
0x6d640000 - 0x6d649000     C:\jdk1.6.0_01\jre\bin\nio.dll
0x71c60000 - 0x71c65000     C:\Windows\System32\wshtcpip.dll
0x74970000 - 0x749b4000     C:\Windows\system32\DNSAPI.dll
0x05080000 - 0x050a5000     C:\Program Files\Bonjour\mdnsNSP.dll
0x75090000 - 0x750ac000     C:\Windows\system32\Iphlpapi.DLL
0x75080000 - 0x75087000     C:\Windows\system32\WINNSI.DLL
0x050c0000 - 0x050c6000     C:\Windows\system32\rasadhlp.dll
0x6f020000 - 0x6f058000     C:\Windows\System32\fwpuclnt.dll
0x70a30000 - 0x70a40000     C:\Windows\system32\NLAapi.dll
0x050d0000 - 0x050d8000     C:\Windows\System32\winrnr.dll
0x050e0000 - 0x050f0000     C:\Windows\system32\napinsp.dll
0x05180000 - 0x05192000     C:\Windows\system32\pnrpnsp.dll
0x74af0000 - 0x74b06000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTSP.dll
0x748c0000 - 0x748fb000     C:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
0x05e90000 - 0x05f4d000     C:\dev\infopae\infopae.libs\cd.dll
0x76f10000 - 0x76f8b000     C:\Windows\system32\comdlg32.dll
0x6e350000 - 0x6e3d3000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.7100.19_none_fadd78f501c74761\COMCTL32.dll
0x05400000 - 0x05412000     C:\dev\infopae\infopae.libs\cdgdiplus.dll
0x71230000 - 0x713c0000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.gdiplus_6595b64144ccf1df_1.1.7100.0_none_69badf24eb1ea50c\gdiplus.dll
0x05f50000 - 0x05fd1000     C:\dev\infopae\infopae.libs\iup.dll
0x05430000 - 0x05435000     C:\dev\infopae\infopae.libs\cdiup.dll
0x05fe0000 - 0x0608b000     C:\dev\infopae\infopae.libs\cdpdflib.dll
0x06090000 - 0x0614f000     C:\dev\infopae\infopae.libs\im.dll
0x06150000 - 0x0618a000     C:\dev\infopae\infopae.libs\im_process.dll
0x06190000 - 0x06261000     C:\dev\infopae\infopae.libs\libeay32.dll
0x750b0000 - 0x750b7000     C:\Windows\system32\WSOCK32.dll
0x06270000 - 0x06299000     C:\dev\infopae\infopae.libs\NCSUtil.dll
0x71c50000 - 0x71c59000     C:\Windows\system32\VERSION.dll
0x77130000 - 0x7715a000     C:\Windows\system32\imagehlp.dll
0x7c3a0000 - 0x7c41b000     C:\Windows\system32\MSVCP71.dll
0x05440000 - 0x05458000     C:\dev\infopae\infopae.libs\NCScnet.dll
0x75460000 - 0x7557c000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPT32.dll
0x75320000 - 0x7532c000     C:\Windows\system32\MSASN1.dll
0x06410000 - 0x06544000     C:\dev\infopae\infopae.libs\NCSEcw.dll
0x70b70000 - 0x70b91000     C:\Windows\system32\ntmarta.dll
0x76c70000 - 0x76cb5000     C:\Windows\system32\WLDAP32.dll
0x06550000 - 0x0672e000     C:\dev\infopae\infopae.libs\lti_dsdk_dll.dll
0x062b0000 - 0x062d7000     C:\dev\infopae\infopae.libs\ssleay32.dll
0x062e0000 - 0x062f3000     C:\dev\infopae\infopae.libs\zlib1.dll
0x06730000 - 0x0680b000     C:\dev\infopae\infopae.libs\libiconv-2.dll
0x06320000 - 0x0632d000     C:\dev\infopae\infopae.libs\libintl-2.dll
0x63100000 - 0x63121000     C:\dev\infopae\infopae.libs\libpq.dll
0x71ce0000 - 0x71ce5000     C:\Windows\system32\SHFOLDER.DLL
0x06810000 - 0x06918000     C:\dev\infopae\infopae.libs\libmysql.dll
0x06340000 - 0x06355000     C:\dev\infopae\infopae.libs\pthreadVC2.dll
0x06a40000 - 0x06be6000     C:\dev\infopae\infopae.libs\log4cxx.dll
0x5a2b0000 - 0x5a33a000     C:\Windows\system32\ODBC32.dll
0x624e0000 - 0x62518000     C:\Windows\system32\odbcint.dll
0x06d70000 - 0x06e6b000     C:\dev\infopae\infopae.libs\geos_fw.dll
0x063b0000 - 0x063c2000     C:\dev\infopae\infopae.libs\zlib_fw.dll
0x06cf0000 - 0x06d0b000     C:\dev\infopae\infopae.libs\jpeg_fw.dll
0x06e70000 - 0x06ee0000     C:\dev\infopae\infopae.libs\libtiff_fw.dll
0x06d10000 - 0x06d2f000     C:\dev\infopae\infopae.libs\geotiff_fw.dll
0x06ee0000 - 0x06fc8000     C:\dev\infopae\infopae.libs\hdf5dll.dll
0x06fd0000 - 0x0705c000     C:\dev\infopae\infopae.libs\hdf_fw.dll
0x07060000 - 0x0707d000     C:\dev\infopae\infopae.libs\jpeg_osgeo.dll
0x07080000 - 0x070ab000     C:\dev\infopae\infopae.libs\libcurl.dll
0x070b0000 - 0x070d5000     C:\dev\infopae\infopae.libs\libexpat.dll
0x070e0000 - 0x070f8000     C:\dev\infopae\infopae.libs\mfhdf_fw.dll
0x07100000 - 0x07129000     C:\dev\infopae\infopae.libs\NCSUtil_fw.dll
0x07130000 - 0x07148000     C:\dev\infopae\infopae.libs\NCScnet_fw.dll
0x07280000 - 0x073b1000     C:\dev\infopae\infopae.libs\NCSEcw_fw.dll
0x073c0000 - 0x073f8000     C:\dev\infopae\infopae.libs\proj.dll
0x07400000 - 0x07438000     C:\dev\infopae\infopae.libs\proj_fw.dll
0x07440000 - 0x07473000     C:\dev\infopae\infopae.libs\netcdf.dll
0x07150000 - 0x0716e000     C:\dev\infopae\infopae.libs\ogdi_fw.dll
0x07480000 - 0x074e0000     C:\dev\infopae\infopae.libs\sqlite3.dll
0x07660000 - 0x078a1000     C:\dev\infopae\infopae.libs\xerces-c_2_6.dll
0x074e0000 - 0x074f2000     C:\dev\infopae\infopae.libs\zlib_osgeo.dll
0x2d800000 - 0x2df45000     C:\dev\infopae\infopae.libs\gdal_fw.dll
0x2df50000 - 0x2e686000     C:\dev\infopae\infopae.libs\tdkjavabinding.dll
0x6d480000 - 0x6d4a2000     C:\Windows\system32\GLU32.dll
0x65840000 - 0x65908000     C:\Windows\system32\OPENGL32.dll
0x573b0000 - 0x57497000     C:\Windows\system32\DDRAW.dll
0x70f50000 - 0x70f56000     C:\Windows\system32\DCIMAN32.dll
0x76f90000 - 0x7712d000     C:\Windows\system32\SETUPAPI.dll
0x75380000 - 0x753a7000     C:\Windows\system32\CFGMGR32.dll
0x75440000 - 0x75452000     C:\Windows\system32\DEVOBJ.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Xms256m -Xmx512m -Djava.library.path=../infopae.libs -Dinfopae.logging.config=../infopae.util/src/conf/logging.conf -Dinfopae.config=../infopae.main/src/conf/infopae.conf -Dinfopae.docroots.path=/InfoPAE/Unidades/PROTOTIPO_TRANSPETRO -Dinfopae.db.server=caja -Dinfopae.db.port=1695 -Dinfopae.db.name=DEMA_TAAR -Dinfopae.i18n.path=../infopae.util/src/i18n/ -Dinfopae.cenario.variavel.grafica.imagem=../infopae.editorprocedimento.ui/src/resources/images/eventos/ -Dinfopae.repositorioInfopae.habilitar=true -Dinfopae.map.disable=false -Dinfopae.metadados.habilitar=true -Dinfopae.debug.console.enabled=true -Dinfopae.hide.tipo.ponto.variavel=false -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
java_command: infopae.main.Main
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
JAVA_HOME=c:\jdk1.6.0_01
CLASSPATH=.;C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\ext\QTJava.zip
PATH=c:/jdk1.6.0_01/bin/../jre/bin/client;c:/jdk1.6.0_01/bin/../jre/bin;c:\svn\bin;c:\scripts;C:\Users\dema\bin;c:\ruby\bin;c:\jruby\bin;c:\apache-ant-1.7.0\bin;c:\apache-maven-2.0.9\bin;c:\jdk1.6.0_01\bin;c:\scala-2.7.4.final\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Git\bin;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files\Bitvise Tunnelier;C:\Program Files\QuickTime\QTSystem\
USERNAME=dema
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=x86 Family 6 Model 15 Stepping 6, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows NT 6.1 Build 7100 

CPU:total 2 family 6, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2

Memory: 4k page, physical 2088120k(733840k free), swap 4185272k(2078880k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (1.6.0_01-b06) for windows-x86, built on Mar 14 2007 00:24:02 by "java_re" with unknown MS VC++:1310
```

Comment: Is your version of Vista 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: Upon further inspection of your error, is your ntdll.dll file the same on both XP and Vista?

Comment: 32-bit
NTDLL.DLL probably differ as it is a system library.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps your problem is mixing c runtime libraries because you updated your C compiler? I see in your stack dump both msvcr71.dll and msvcrt.dll. According to this [Microsoft Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abx4dbyh%28VS.71%29.aspx)

> If your DLLs pass CRT resources across the msvcrt.dll and msvcr71.dll boundary, you will encounter issues with mismatched CRTs and need to recompile your project

The implication seems to be that JNI extensions should use the same compiler/runtime as used to build the jre, but I can't find any reference to say that is so. I'd welcome another answer telling my why I am wrong and how I can get around the same problem myself.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting up WinDBG, and hook up a symbol server, so you can get symbols for the OS DLLs.

- [WinDBG](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/debugging/default.mspx)
- [Symbols](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/debugging/debugstart.mspx)
  (bottom of the page)

Then run your Java app under WinDBG and trap the crash there. With any luck you should be able to find your native code in the call stack, or at least something you can recognize.